# How to get a substring from the text of an input field and display it to another html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str1=$("#account-number").val().substring(0,4);
$("#first-four").html(str1);
```

I have tried multiple variations and attempts its been a few hours... so I thought I should ask for help...

I want to be able to take the first four characters of an input field with id "account-number" and send it to a div with id "first-four"

Comment: So how are you calling the code above? Do you trigger it when the input changes?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/6vc6jge9/

Comment: @user3498863 You're using jQuery.  Make sure you're linking to the jQuery library/file so your code has access to its objects and methods.

Comment: EXCELLENT it works well

Answer (score 1):

On thing to watch out for is **change** vs **input**.  The first only fires when the input looses focus.

```js
$("#account-number").on("input", function(){
  $("#first-four").text(this.value.substring(0,4));
});
```

```html
<input id="account-number" type="text" />
<div id="first-four"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#account-number" ).on("input", function() {
        var str1 = $("#account-number").val().substring(0,4);
        $("#first-four").html(str1);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#account-number").blur(function(){
        var accountNmbr = $("#account-number").val().substring(0,4);
        $("#first-four").html(accountNmbr);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw4kr4Lq/